# Informix 12.10 - How to remove non-numeric characters in a string?

Tags: informix

I'm new to Informix and I need to fix some data.

Does Informix 12:10 support regex? Or is there a built-in function for this purpose?

I'm after a way to strip non-numeric characters in a string?

Answer (score 3):

You should have access to regex support if you have version 12.10.FC8 or later (12.10.FC11 is the latest version). Check this link:

- [Regex Pattern Matching](http://informix.hcldoc.com/help/topic/com.ibm.dbext.doc/ids_dbxt_544.htm)

If your table is `example` and the column to be fixed is `name`, then you might select the converted values using:

```
SELECT regex_replace(name, '[^0-9]', '')
  FROM example
 WHERE name MATCHES '*[^0-9]*'
```

You could use an UPDATE statement to fix the data:

```
UPDATE example
   SET name = regex_replace(name, '[^0-9]', '')
 WHERE name MATCHES '*[^0-9]*'
```

Comment: In which sub-version of 12.10 did the regex blade become available?  I'm not finding it in 12.10.FC6 on macOS 10.13.4, which might be a Mac issue or a version issue.  A search `grep -ril -e regex $INFORMIXDIR/release` doesn't find any mention of regex in the release notes at all, so it is likely it was added after the FC6 release.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler According to the release notes, the regex blade become available in Informix version 12.10.XC8.

Comment: I'm on 12.10.FC5

Regex function unavailable?

674: Routine (regex_replace) can not be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

yes, use MATCHES key word

```
WHERE lname NOT MATCHES 'Baxter*'
```

please see this link [MATCHES operator](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_14.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1389.htm)